# Need some clarify on this creation of a new variable through array do looping,

Tags: arrays, sas

Below, i have a piece of SAS code. The variable **AEACN** is a character variable and has the same values as the declared temporary character array variable **text1**. I have created another character array variable **num** with values from 1 to 5. I'm checking if the variable **AEACN** values with the values present in the temporary character array variable **text1** and if they are equal, then I'm assigning values 1 to 5 accordingly. The variable **AEACN** is not null. But still the variable **C9** is not getting populated.

```
array text1[5] $ _temporary_ ( "DOSE NOT CHANGED"
                                 "DRUG INTERRUPTED"
                                 "DRUG WITHDRAWN" 
                                 "NOT APPLICABLE"
                                 "UNKNOWN" ) ;
array num[5] ( "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" ) ;

do i = 1 to 5 ;
    if strip ( upcase ( aeacn ) ) = text1[i] then c9 = num[i] ;
end;
```

I'm have been at it for quiet sometime. The problem is right under my nose I feel. I need a third person's view on this piece of code.

Comment: you just add debuging statements inside the do loop.  for each run of the loop, you must print out on your terminal, 1) the value of i, 2)the value of aeacn, 3) the value of upcae(aeacn)  4) the value of strip(upcase)(aeacn)) 5) the value of text1[i].  do that and edit in the results here

Comment: PS your variable naming is not good.  you should change to **meaningful variable names**.  this is the biggest problem you are facing here.

Comment: I don't quiet understand. You want me to use debug option and check for each iteration?

Comment: Yes. Add some code which prints out what I mentioned, on each iteration of the do loop.

Comment: I have renamed the variables on purpose while putting the code here. And yes, I figured it out. I had not assigned the length for the array variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array refers to variables, so when defining an array you need to assign variable names (and if the case initial values) not the values in a variable.

To recode a variable, you need to use a format:

```
proc format;
value $DRUG
   "DOSE NOT CHANGED"="1"
   "DRUG INTERRUPTED"="2"
   "DRUG WITHDRAWN"  ="3"
   "NOT APPLICABLE"  ="4"
   "UNKNOWN"         ="5"
;
run;

data MyDataSet;                
    set MyDataSet;              
    c9=put(strip(upcase(aeacn)),$DRUG.);
run;
```